# Ubuntu 18.04: Cannot extract downloaded tar.xz file with a single command

Tags: linux, curl, tar, ubuntu-18.04, xz

I am trying to download and extract `tar.xz` file with a single line command. However, it doesn't consistently work for all of the links. I can manually download and extract it.

I am able to download glibc and extract without any issue.

```
curl https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/glibc/glibc-2.26.tar.xz | tar -xJ -C ${PWD} --strip-components 1
```

When it comes to download the following file, it surprisingly fails. I couldn't find out what makes the difference. This is the single link I have seen so far which fails.

Any idea why the following command fails?

```
curl https://releases.linaro.org/components/toolchain/binaries/7.4-2019.02/arm-linux-gnueabihf/gcc-linaro-7.4.1-2019.02-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf.tar.xz | tar -xJ -C ${PWD} --strip-components 1
```

It fails with the following message.

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
xz: (stdin): File format not recognized
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `curl -L` to follow redirects:

```
curl -L https://releases.linaro.org/components/toolchain/binaries/7.4-2019.02/arm-linux-gnueabihf/gcc-linaro-7.4.1-2019.02-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf.tar.xz | tar -xJ --strip-components 1
```

To debug such issues, you can run the `curl` command by itself and observe that in this case, it doesn't return any data:

```
$ curl https://releases.linaro.org/components/toolchain/binaries/7.4-2019.02/arm-linux-gnueabihf/gcc-linaro-7.4.1-2019.02-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf.tar.xz
$
```

You can then further run `curl -v` to see what's going on. It shows a `HTTP/1.1 302 Found` with an empty body and a redirection to a different file, which is how you know to add `-L` to follow the redirection.

Comment: Thanks for the debugging tips and solution